# Samba is installed, Why doesn't gnome-file-share-properties work?

Tags: samba, file-sharing

Samba and all it's dependencies are installed. Why does `gnome-file-share-properties` (Personal File Sharing application) say:

```
This feature cannot be enabled because the required packages are not installed on your system ?
```

What packages am I missing?

**EDIT:**
Personal File Sharing application may also be known by gnome-user-share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this, you need to install two (2) more packages. Type these on a Terminal then try again

`sudo apt-get install apache2.2-bin libapache2-mod-dnssd`

Comment: apache2.2-bin grabbed 5 dependencies also. Works now. Thanks @zeroseven0183

Comment: Sure. Have fun!

Comment: On 14.04, apache-2.2-bin removed the gnome-user-share package for me. So I only needed libapache2-mod-dnssd.

Answer (score 0):

This answer must be too dated to work. I did not pay attention to the fact this was asked 7 years ago! 
My result doing `sudo apt-get install apache2.2-bin libapache2-mod-dnssd`  did what was explained in comment by – Nik Reiman Feb 4 '15 at 8:28

I had to do `sudo apt-get install gnome-user-share` to fix it